# Unexplained scala boxing exception

Tags: json, scala, generics, classcastexception, type-erasure

I am seeing some strange (un)boxing behaviour in Scala I cannot explain.

Consider the following code:

```
case class SomeCaseClass(longOpt: Option[Long])

def someMethod(l: Long): Unit = ???

val x: SomeCaseClass = // Case class populated from JSON in some code I do not control

x.longOpt.map(l => someMethod(l))
```

The attempt to call `someMethod` yields the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at scala.runtime.BoxesRuntime.unboxToLong(BoxesRuntime: 105)
```

Running the following:

```
x.longOpt.map(_.getClass).get
```

yields long

Obviously the conversion of JSON to the case class is the prime suspect but I would expect a runtime error instantiating the case class if the value was not of the correct type.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: I would report a bug in the **Json** library and even better use a different one.

Comment: I am sure the Json library is the cause - I want to understand why Scala does not complain when the case class is created, only when I attempt to manipulate the Option[Long] which it would appear does not contain a Long at all...

Comment: Because probably the **Long** was not created in **Scala**. This sounds like the result of _runtime reflection_ or an `asInstanceOf`. May I ask which **json** library are you using?

Comment: Sadly it is an in house library - I will dig out the code and take a look.

Comment: I know SO is not a place for advice and opinions, but... I really really would recommend you not to have your own **Json** library, it is not as easy as it sounds and there are a lot of great quality libraries out there like **circe**, **play-json**, **jason4s**. **jsonitter-scala**

Comment: Oh - I know but I don't make the decisions :)

Answer (score 2):

> Obviously the conversion of JSON to the case class is the prime suspect but I would expect a runtime error instantiating the case class if the value was not of the correct type.

> I want to understand why Scala does not complain when the case class is created, only when I attempt to manipulate the `Option[Long]` which it would appear does not contain a Long at all...

I guess the thing is in type erasure. For

```
case class SomeCaseClass(longOpt: Option[Long])
```

`Option[Long]` is just `Option[_]` at runtime. So there is no `ClassCastException` during instantiating the case class because it's not casting `Option[Integer]` to `Option[Long]`, it's `Option[_]` to `Option[_]`.

And when you work with the content of `Option` it's `ClassCastException` because you try to cast `Integer` to `Long`.

Comment: A simple way to replicate this would be `val ints = List("Foo", "Bar").asInstanceOf[List[Int]]` which works but once you use it like `ints.head` it fails.